# find all id with a specific string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get all the `href` tags of all links on a page, and put them in an array. I have the following code, but when I check the console I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'attr'` I'm not to sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

**Code**

```
function videoLinks() {
    var videoLinks = $("a[id^=a_l_]").each(function() {
        var linkArray = jQuery.makeArray(videoLinks);
        console.log(linkArray.attr("href"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) returns a native JavaScript array, not a jQuery object. Native JavaScript arrays do not have jQuery methods like `.attr()`. Is this starting to make sense?

Passing `videoLinks` to `$.makeArray` simply does not make sense, since you're either passing the function `videoLinks`, or the function-local `videoLinks` which is *already* a jQuery object. So, I think this is more along the lines of what you're trying to do:

```
function videoLinks() {
    $("a[id^=a_l_]").each(function() {
        console.log(this.href);
    });
}
```

That will log the `href` attribute of every `<a>` element with an `id` that starts with `'a_l_'`. Perhaps instead you'd like to build up an array of those `href` attributes instead of logging them. Then you'd use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
function videoLinks() {
    var hrefs = $("a[id^=a_l_]").map(function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get(); // ← note the .get() call
}
```

> my ultimate goal is to return one of the links at random

Then you're almost there. [Just get a random element from the `hrefs` array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array):

```
function videoLinks() {
    var hrefs = $("a[id^=a_l_]").map(function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get(); // ← note the .get() call

    var randHref = hrefs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hrefs.length)];
    console.log(randHref);
}
```

Comment: wow that simple :) well that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. thank you very much.

Comment: ok yes my ultimate goal is to return one of the links at random

Comment: Now, why didn't you say so in the first place? `:)` Edited.

Comment: haha sorry about that, but you're a pro! I have some studying to do on this thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me .. (from 'Matt Ball' code above)

```
$("a[id^=a_l_]").each(function() {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
```